# GTK+ installed with brew is not found when I try to compile other applications

Tags: macos, gtk, homebrew

I installed GTK with `brew install gtk+` as I need it to compile xchat from source on my Mac. When I try to install it tough, it says `Cannot find GTK! Not building GTK FrontEnd.`
 I suspect I should've updated the environment variables once installed gtk+ but I don't know how.

```
iMac:xchat-2.8.8 Domenico$ brew info gtk+
gtk+: stable 2.24.20
http://gtk.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.20 (1184 files, 52M) * // here is the path!!!
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/gtk+.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config, xz
Required: glib, jpeg, libtiff, gdk-pixbuf, pango, atk, cairo
Optional: jasper
==> Options
--with-jasper
    Build with jasper support
```

The path is listed in the code above. I tried adding all kind of things related to it (e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.20/bin` or `/usr/local/Cellar`) to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem yet? I'm having exactly the same problem while trying to ./configure hexchat, which is based on xchat. Already installed gtk+, but somehow it's still not found. I also tried adding a few paths to my bash_profile but it didn't help either. Aditionally, glib is not found by configure for me, too, although it's installed in is latest version. I'm on Mavericks, if that helps in any way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue, pkg-config wasn't able to find gettext because homebrew didn't link it by default. You can --force link it, then compile, then unlink it again to prevent unintended behaviour.

Comment: Why don't you install `xchat` using `homebew`?

Answer (score 2):

I had smiliar issues with after `brew install gtk+`. Specifically, I got:

```
    Package xcb-shm was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xcb-shm.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'xcb-shm', required by 'cairo', not found
    app.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [app] Error 1
```

while running `make` for my app and this command solved my problem:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig`

The extended answer on this problem has been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23988317/4694621.

---

This might be an issue since `gtk+` depends on these libraries ([source](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/introduction/)):

```
Glib
Pango
ATK
GDK
GdkPixbuf
Cairo
```